# What is the maximum theoretical speed-up due to SSE for a simple binary subtraction?

Tags: c, optimization, sse, vectorization

In trying to figure out whether or not my code's inner loop is hitting a hardware design barrier or a lack of understanding on my part barrier.  There's a bit more to it, but the simplest question I can come up with to answer is as follows:

If I have the following code:

```
float px[32768],py[32768],pz[32768];
float xref, yref, zref, deltax, deltay, deltaz;

initialize_with_random(px);
initialize_with_random(py);
initialize_with_random(pz);

for(i=0;i<32768-1;i++) {
  xref=px[i];
  yref=py[i];
  zref=pz[i];
  for(j=0;j<32768-1;j++ {
    deltx=xref-px[j];
    delty=yref-py[j];
    deltz=zref-pz[j];
  } }
```

What type of maximum theoretical speed up would I be able to see by going to SSE instructions in a situation where I have complete control over code (assembly, intrinsics, whatever) but no control over runtime environment other than architecture (i.e. it's a multi-user environment so I can't do anything about how the OS kernel assigns time to my particular process).

Right now I'm seeing a speed up of 3x with my code, when I would have thought using SSE would give me much more vector depth than the 3x speed up is indicating (presumably the 3x speed up tells me I have a 4x maximum theoretical throughput).  (I've tried things such as letting deltx/delty/deltz be arrays in case the compiler wasn't smart enough to auto-promote them, but I still see only 3x speed up.)  I'm using the intel C compiler with the appropriate compiler flags for vectorization, but no intrinsics obviously.

Comment: stupid question, but does removing the `-1` from the for conditions change anything? (your loop runs from 0 to 32766 instead of 32767)

Comment: No, it's an arbitrary number.  In actual production code that number would be variable anyway.  (Which means I'll eventually have to hand unroll the loop into register sized chunks I believe and handle the terminal case with extra logic.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the CPU. But the theoretical max won't get above 4x. I don't know of a CPU which can execute more than one SSE instruction per clock cycle, which means that it can *at most* compute 4 values per cycle.

Most CPU's can do *at least* one floating point scalar instruction per cycle, so in this case you'd see a theoretical max of a 4x speedup.

But you'll have to look up the specific instruction throughput for the CPU you're running on.

A practical speedup of 3x is pretty good though.

Comment: Practical speedups higher than 4x are _kind of_ possible, at least in some situations, and on some models. I once had one big manufacturer's CPU easily outperform the competitor's 2-generations newer model on code that did a considerable amount of _both_ vector and scalar calculations (with modest memory pressure). It turned out that on the "older, slower" CPU, the non-SSE code exectured entirely out of order and "for free" while the SSE code was running. Though this was admittedly a really special case, I'd assume that an optimizing compiler might achieve similar on small scale.

Comment: Most SSE instructions have 2 or 3 instructions per-clock throughput on modern x86 (like Skylake).  FP math is 2 / clock.  On Nehalem (current in 2009), yes 1/clock for SIMD FP add and mul, but they need different ports so they could run in parallel with each other.  https://agner.org/optimize/

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd probably have to interleave the inner loop somehow. The 3-component vector is getting done at once, but that's only 3 operations at once. To get to 4, you'd do 3 components from the first vector, and 1 from the next, then 2 and 2, and so on. If you established some kind of queue that loads and processes the data 4 components at a time, then separate it after, that might work.

Edit: You could unroll the inner loop to do 4 vectors per iteration (assuming the array size is always a multiple of 4). That would accomplish what I said above.

Answer (score 1):

Consider: How wide is a float? How wide is the SSEx instruction? The ratio should should give you some kind of reasonable upper bound.

It's also worth noting that out-of-order pipes play havok with getting good estimates of speedup.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider [loop tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_tiling) - the way you are accessing values in the inner loop is probably causing a lot of thrashing in the L1 data cache. It's not too bad, because everything probably still fits in the L2 at 384 KB, but there is easily an order of magnitude difference between an L1 cache hit and an L2 cache hit, so this could make a big difference for you.